Does IfPackageLoadedTF neutralize xpatch?
This is an admittedly strange question.
The background is the
suggestion from StackExchange to use package xpatch
to keep latexmk running a TEX file although included graphic files or in this case listings or that like are to be created later.
This works quite well.
Unfortunately, I must modify the solution a bit but this renders it unusable:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\IfPackageLoadedTF{listings}{%% added 
\typeout{>>>>>>listings loaded}%% added 

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NewLine}{^^J}%
\xpatchcmd{\lst@MissingFileError}
  {Package Listings Error: File `#1(.#2)' not found.}
  {LaTeX Error: File `#1.#2' not found.\NewLine}{%
    \typeout{File ending patch for \string\lst@MissingFileError\space done.}%
  }{%
    \typeout{File ending patch for \string\lst@MissingFileError\space failed.}%
  }
\makeatother
}{% added 
   \typeout{>>>>>>listings not loaded}%% added 
}% added 

\begin{document}
Test
%\lstinputlisting{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}
\lstinputlisting[language=TeX, basicstyle=\tiny,
breaklines, lastline=25,
float, captionpos=b, label={lst:ptx}, 
caption={The ptx-file for a fig-file}]{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}
\end{document}

The original solution is without enclosing \IfPackageLoadedTF and works fine,
whereas with \IfPackageLoadedTF it does not any more.
The result is as if the patch is not applied at all.
My first idea was, that maybe listings is somehow unloaded,
but output shows that it is loaded.
Who can help???

Unrelated to the specific command but you need to move makeatletter and makeatother out of the argument, they must be at the top level

@DavidCarlisle sounds good, but did not work for me... Maybe this is one step and another one is needed in addition?
Why is makeatletter and makeatother only usable top level?

you need @ to be a letter when the argument is parsed,  after the argument is grabbed makeatletter will have no effect on the tokens that have already been made. Once \lst@MissingFileError has been parsed as \lst @  M i s s i n g F i l e E r r o r it is that many tokens and \makeatletter will not make it into  as single \lst@MissingFileError token

@DavidCarlisle Thank you

I can reproduce the exact errors you get with the provided “solution”:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newif\iflistingsloaded
\IfPackageLoadedTF{listings}{%
  \typeout{>>>>>>listings loaded}%
  \listingsloadedtrue
}{%
  \typeout{>>>>>>listings not loaded}%
  \listingsloadedfalse
}

\iflistingsloaded
  \makeatletter
  \usepackage{xpatch}
  \newcommand*{\NewLine}{^^J}%
  \xpatchcmd{\lst@MissingFileError}
    {Package Listings Error: File `#1(.#2)' not found.}
    {LaTeX Error: File `#1.#2' not found.\NewLine}
    {\typeout{File ending patch for \string\lst@MissingFileError\space done.}}
    {\typeout{File ending patch for \string\lst@MissingFileError\space failed.}}
  \makeatother
\fi

\begin{document}

Test
%\lstinputlisting{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}
\lstinputlisting[language=TeX, basicstyle=\tiny,
breaklines, lastline=25,
float, captionpos=b, label={lst:ptx}, 
caption={The ptx-file for a fig-file}]{F4_01fig2dev.ptx}

\end{document}

If you pass the \xpatchcmd as the argument to a command it won't work.

Works for me.
Nevertheless, the way you formulate your answer is so that I understand, that the code you provide reproduces my problem. Maybe because with my code you cant.
In fact it is the other way round: your code provides the solution.

@David: This solution comprises yours in a sense.
So, maybe both \makeat... and \xpathcmd must be top level.
